# jQuery Mobile: Popup dialog not expanding to fit it's content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having a hard time getting the popup dialog to expand to fit it's content, no matter how wide I expand the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/LZxxB/45/

```
    <a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
         <h1>Hello</h1>

    </div>


    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><h4 style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;" id="endGameLine3" >This is the left text</h4></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><h4 style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;" id="endGameLine4" >THIS SHOULD NOT WRAP</h4></div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your text content should be *inside* the `<h4>` elements if you want `white-space: nowrap` to apply to it.

Comment: Thanks, still the same issue. Question updated

Comment: check this you want like this or someother http://jsfiddle.net/LZxxB/47/

Comment: @Aravinth no, the popup should not stretch to the width of the window, it should only stretch as far as the content inside it

Comment: "girds" don't stretch to width of its' contents. They stretch to parent's width. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LZxxB/48/

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **css**

```
#popupDialog-popup{
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/LZxxB/44/)

Comment: Thanks but that is 100% of the page, not the width of the content